# Why doesn't my Makefile work when i do something like this?

Tags: c++, makefile

[image: My files (TestRepo is not important]

This Makefile works properly but is very long and i don't like it.

```
myprog: main.o general.o apple.o
    g++ -o myprog main.o general.o apple.o

main.o: main.cpp general.h apple.h
    g++ -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wall -c main.cpp -Wl,-dead_strip

general.o: general.cpp general.h
    g++ -Wall -c general.cpp

apple.o: apple.cpp general.h
    g++ -Wall -c apple.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

But this Makefile cannot work at all:

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall

sources=main.cpp general.cpp apple.cpp
headers=general.h apple.h
objects=$(sources:.cpp=.o)

%: %.o
    $(LINK.cpp) -o $@ $^

myprog:$(objects)
main.o: main.cpp general.h apple.h
general.o: general.cpp general.h
apple.o: apple.cpp general.h

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

I would like to have a short and working Makefile but i am lost. I have seen many posts about Makefiles but i dont fully understand why mine doesn't work.
What is wrong with my 2nd Makefile ?
Do you have a template of a short Makefile i can use ?

Comment: Is there any error message when using the second makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that using "LINK.cpp" it didn't work. I have replaced 2 lines and it's now working fine.
The code that is working :

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall 

sources=main.cpp general.cpp apple.cpp
headers=general.h apple.h
objects=$(sources:.cpp=.o)

myprog:$(objects)
    g++ -o $@ $^

main.o: main.cpp general.h apple.h
general.o: general.cpp general.h
apple.o: apple.cpp general.h

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

However i am not sure if it's the best Makefile i can make if anyone has suggestions or remarks i would be happy to read them.

Comment: Some options, notably `-g` for debug, should be passed to both the compiler for creating the objects and to the linker for creating executables.  You should use macros for the options like that.

Comment: A moderately typical linker line might consist almost entirely of macros: `${CXX} -o $@ ${CXXFLAGS} $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}` (with appropriate definitions for each macro).  The `${LDFLAGS}` and `${LDLIBS}` macros are usually empty by default, but allow you to craft the correct command line (libraries after object files).